# change attr with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to change the value to the src attr of the img tag

html

```
<div  class="testBg"><img src="images/skins/picture.jpg"/></div>
```

js

```
$(".testBg").find('img').attr('src').val('newpic.jpg');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".testBg img").attr('src', 'new_src_value');
```

Comment: This syntax is right on but I would probably change my select code to be $("div.testBg img") to make things faster. I know Blainer gave the example of the class selector but I would avoid using only the class selector to speed up your pages. In older browser such as IE6/7 and Firefox 2 jQuery has to spider every element on page. By giving the selector a prefix, div, it speeds things up.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the actual attribute name (`src`):

```
$(".testBg").find('img').attr('src', 'newpic.jpg');
```

Also, you can select the `img` directly:

```
$(".testBg img").attr('src', 'newpic.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".testBg").find('img').attr('src','yourvalue');
```

Check this out: [jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)